# Spring Boot Exception(Error) Handling for RESTful Services

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have the following `RESTful Services method` :

```
@PostMapping("/ajouterNewField")
public String ajouterField(@Valid @ModelAttribute("field") Fields field, Model model) throws IOException {  

    fieldDao.save(field);
    // SOME CODE 
    return displayListeChamps( model);
}
```

The method is working fine and my question is how to handle any error (database not connected ...) or every issue that can happen durring the execution of this `RESTful Services method`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll have to a sort of exception handler for any kind of exception your method might throw:

```
public class FooController{

    //  ...
    @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class })
    public void handleException() {
    //
    }
}
```

Here's a nice article about that: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice`
Refer to the code below

```
@ControllerAdvice
public String NyExceptionHandlerAdvice {
    private final Logger logger = ...;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler({MyRunTimeException.class})
    public void handleMyRunTimeException(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception : ", e);
    }
    return MY_ERROR_STRING;
}
```

Best Practice is:
You can have your code throw RunTimeExceptions and handle all of them together or separately in handler methods similar to `handleMyRunTimeException` above.

You can decide what status code your request should return upon exception.

Comment: update: i have drafted my understanding around @ControllerAdvice in [How to handle exceptions is Spring Rest Service](http://www.amitph.com/spring-rest-service-exception-handling/)